# Output an attribute of an element that is found by contains function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xsl code. All I want to do is, output the cat attribute of the word that is found with contains function. Code outputs true right now (as i understand the reason) but how can i output its attribute value?

```
<xsl:value-of select="contains($grammar//lexicalRules, 'likes')"></xsl:value-of>
```

My $grammar is something likes this

```
<lexicalRules>
        <word cat="vp">snores</word>
        <word cat="vt">likes</word>
</lexicalRules>
```

In this case i want to output vt.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$grammar//lexicalRules/word[. = 'likes']/@cat
```